# How to stop Xubuntu from falling asleep on lid close

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, power-management

I'm on a current Xubuntu LTS, but this problem has annoyed me for years, and i just didn't say anything about it.

Using notebooks and often using an external monitor to watch films, porn, etc i would like to have an ability to close the lid of the monitor and for the notebook monitor to be just turnt off, and not some sort of sleep/hibernate/turn off action.

Can it be easily done? If so then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start **System Settings**
2. Go to **Hardware** Section
3. Open **Power Manager**
4. On **General** tab
5. There is a settings called **When laptop lid is closed** . Change it to do **Switch off display**

[image: Laptop lid close settings]

Comment: Mine says 'Lock screen'

Comment: change it to "Switch off display". IT will only switch off it. however, if you want it to lock also, use can use lock.